# Off-center parting line?

Tags: packages, wirebonding

Older Micron TSOP packages advertise a feature, “off-center parting line.” What does this refer to? Is this a feature of the lead frame? I have heard that OCPL has some vague mechanical reliability or maybe packaging yield benefits. Can anyone discuss OCPL in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a mechanical arrangement that allows packages to be stacked. From a [patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/e5/9b/a5/622608ea70c6e3/US20110248391A1.pdf).

[image]

From paragraph [0027],

> The top package 102 is mounted over the bottom package 110, such as a TSOP having an off-centered parting line (OCPL) as shown by the position of a bottom lead 112 off-set from center within a bottom pack
> age body 114. It is understood that the bottom lead 112 may be a portion of a lead frame (not shown).

Probably a more modern solution would be to stack dies inside the package, if necessary, to increase density.

Comment: What specifically is the "parting line" being referred to here?

Comment: @Hearth Generally the parting line is on the leadframe plane, so I would assume 122 or 104 or 112-- well, I might as well just look at the reference.  Ah here we go. Well, might as well just add the relevant section since I'm looking at it--. Yep, 112 it is.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. It's hard to imagine the part coming out of the mold if the parting line was not on the same plane as the leadframe.